# Referencing SpotifyWebApi in AndroidStudio

Tags: android

I'm trying to reference SpotifyWebApi in AndroidStudio. I'm using the instructions here

https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/blob/master/README.md

However I get the error 
Error:Failed to resolve: :spotify-web-api-android-0.1.0:

when I try to build.

How can I fix this? I have AndroidStudio 1.2.2

Here's my Module:app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.example.android.spotifystreamerstage1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'spotify-web-api-android-0.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

    // Other dependencies your app might use
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

spotify-web-api-android is not included maven central repository. the doc of the link has wrong info. I don't know why..

Alternatively I have found [this link](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/issues/45) and next codes.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/z0lope0z/raws/raw/master"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'kaaes.spotify.webapi.android:spotify-web-api-android:0.1.0'
}
```